# Stacked loops to calculate average of select columns for large dataset

Tags: r, loops, sequence

I have a large dataset containing the results of various model simulations. I have 84 columns where columns 1-2 are all results of a simulation run with the same parameters, columns 3-4 are the results of the second set of 2 runs with the same parameters (different than the parameters used for runs 1-2), columns 5-6 are a third set of 2 runs with the same parameters (different than the parameters used for previous runs)...etc.

I need code for R that will allow me to average all the row values for simulations run with the same parameters (e.g. average all row values for columns 1-2, then all values for columns 3-4...).

I am using the following code to first generate a sequence of numbers that represents the column numbers for same-model runs according to the number of repeated runs per model (run.num) as well as the total number of runs (total.runs). These variables can change depending on the way I set up the simulation so I want code that will let me automate most steps.

```
# Define parameters of model assessment
run.num <- 2
total.runs <- 84
start.seq <- seq(1, total.runs, run.num)

# Creates empty space for the sequence values
sequences <- data.frame(matrix(total.runs/run.num, run.num))

# Creates the sequences 
for (i in start.seq){
 sequence <- seq(i, i + run.num - 1, 1)
 sequences[i, 1] <- sequence[1]
 sequences[i, 2] <- sequence[2] 
}

# Is there a way to automate how many of these "sequences[i, x] are generated 
based on run.num?

# Remove NA rows
sequences <- sequences[start.seq, ]
```

I end up with a table where each row is a set of model runs and each column contains a "run number" value corresponding to a column. Now I want to use these row numbers (which represent column numbers in my dataset) to create a new data frame (via a loop) containing just the resulting average value of all rows within the columns.

I am not sure if there is an easier way to do this, but basically, I need to have code in which I can specify how many repeated runs were run for each model and get averaged values for each of those repeated runs. It needs to be as automated as possible so that I don't have to change the code too much every time I change how many simulations I run or how many times each simulation is repeated. I couldn't think of a shorter way to explain this and I hope I made it somewhat understandable. Any help is much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I constructed a smaller example with 6 columns, but you should be able to just change `total.runs` back to 84 for your application. I'm setting a random seed for reproducibility. I also put one `NA` value in there just to show you it can handle that. There are likely many ways to implement this but here is one.

```
run.num <- 2
total.runs <- 6
start.seq <- seq(1, total.runs, run.num)

set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(
  c1 = sample(1:10, 100, replace = T),
  c2 = sample(1:10, 100, replace = T),
  c3 = sample(1:10, 100, replace = T),
  c4 = sample(1:10, 100, replace = T),
  c5 = sample(1:10, 100, replace = T),
  c6 = c(NA, sample(1:10, 99, replace = T))
)
```

We first use `lapply` to split the dataframe into a list of dataframes that you want the row sums of. Check out some examples online of `lapply` if this is confusing. This would also work if `run.num` was 3 (but will break on 4 or more since 4 doesn't divide 6).

```
l <- lapply(start.seq, function(x) df[,x:(x + run.num - 1)])
```

We then `lapply` again to take the row sums, and bind the resulting vectors into a dataframe of rowsums.

```
ll <- lapply(l, function(df) rowSums(df, na.rm = T))

bind_cols(ll)
# A tibble: 100 x 3
      V1    V2    V3
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1    10     6     3
 2    19    18    16
 3    20     9    14
 4    10    13     7
 5    15    10    15
 6    17     6     4
 7    11     8     3
 8     9     5    13
 9    10    12    10
10    20     5    14
# ... with 90 more rows
```

And just to check the work of that first column:

```
head(rowSums(df[,1:2], na.rm = T), 10)
 [1] 10 19 20 10 15 17 11  9 10 20
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tidyverse approach. Not sure if I'm understanding the question exactly, but hopefully this shows directionally how it could be solved.

```
library(tidyverse)
cols = 84
result_rows = 100
groupings = 2

fake <- data.frame(column = rep(paste0("Col_", 1:84), each = result_rows),
                   run    = rep(1:result_rows, cols),
                   result  = sample(c(1:10, NA_integer_),  cols * result_rows, replace = T)) %>%
  tidyr::spread(column, result)


output <- fake %>%
  # Pull into "long" format with a new column specifying the source column
  gather(column, result, -run) %>%
  # Extract the number from the column name
  mutate(col_num = str_remove(column, "Col_") %>% as.integer) %>%
  # Calculate what group the column belongs to
  mutate(group   = ceiling(col_num / groupings)) %>%
  # Calculate the mean per group
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarize(avg = mean(result, na.rm = T))
```